# ActiveRecord has_many through has_many relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :social_media_posts
    has_many :twitter_posts, through: :social_media_posts
end

class SocialMediaPost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :twitter_posts, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :twitter_posts
end

class TwitterPost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :social_media_post
    has_one :company, through: :social_media_post
end
```

`TwitterPost` has an attribute called `post_id`, which is the id of a tweet as returned from Twitter's API - not the id of an associated `Post` model. For some reason when I run the following line of code, it breaks:

```
# company.twitter_posts.where.not(post_id: nil).count
# Expected output:
# => 103
```

I get this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "post_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...cial_media_post_id = social_media_posts.id)) AND (post_id IS...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "social_media_posts" WHERE "social_media_posts"."company_id" = $1 AND (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM twitter_posts WHERE twitter_posts.social_media_post_id = social_media_posts.id)) AND (post_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Clearly it's looking for the column `post_id` in the `social_media_posts` table, where there is none. When I call `company.twitter_posts`, I get an `SocialMediaPost::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` relation, when I'd expect to get an `TwitterPost::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` relation. How can I fix this, preferably without changing the schema (though I'd consider it since this isn't on production yet)?

Comment: I think it might be your db schema issue on how it's structured.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah t looks like it can't figure out what association the `post_id` is meant to be on. I'd try being explicit about that eg:

```
 company.twitter_posts.where.not("twitter_posts.post_id" => nil).count
```

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately it didn't work. Now I get:`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "twitter_posts"
LINE 1: ...cial_media_post_id = social_media_posts.id)) AND ("twitter_p...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "social_media_posts" WHERE "social_media_posts"."company_id" = $1 AND (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM twitter_posts WHERE twitter_posts.social_media_post_id = social_media_posts.id)) AND ("twitter_posts"."post_id" IS NOT NULL)`